# better way to shrink copy/paste codes

Tags: c++, enums

Currently I have this trunk of code: a vector of structs `v[myStruct]`. The size of it is 3. I named these structs as `myStruct_A`, `myStruct_B`, and `myStruct_C`. Each piece of code is almost same, but with its name as suffix.

```
SomeMap someMap_A;
for (auto& pair : myStruct_A.hashMap) {
  SomeStruct someStruct = foo(pair);
  someMap_A[someStruct.key] = someStruct.value;
  anotherStruct_A[someStruct.nameX] = someStruct.bundle;
}
someVector.push_back[someMap_A];
```

All of the three A,B,C need do the above things. The question here is that if using a function, I don't know how to separate and specify the names. I need get several vectors of data which are based on all of those three `myStruct`s' outputs.

Comment: what's the suffix for? you wouldn't care how it's named in a function if you pass the struct as parameter.

Comment: They have the same dataTypes. Just different names. What I can think of now is using a `pair` for each struct, with its name for the 2nd entry. But it seems stupid...

Comment: @LeleDumbo you're right...As long as I add them by sequence, I don't care the name. I could just name them when I extract the final results from the vectors.

Comment: As far as I can tell, you just need an ordinary function here, one that takes a reference parameter. And using a pair like you said is indeed stupid and won't work.

Comment: @Tas This is example code which would be closed as off-topic on Code Review

Comment: @Tas More specifically, `SomeMap`, `SomeStruct`, etc. are like `foo` and `bar`, which makes the code unreviewable.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this with a macro. For example, here's a simplified version:

```
#define process(i, suffix)  some_vect_ ## suffix.push_back(i);  \
                            some_set_ ## suffix.insert(i);


int main() { 
    std::vector<int> some_vect_A, some_vect_B, some_vect_C;
    std::set<int> some_set_A, some_set_B, some_set_C;

    for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
        int val = rand();
        process(val, A); // adds `val` to `some_vect_A` and `some_set_A`
        process(val, B); // adds `val` to `some_vect_B` and `some_set_B`
        process(val, C); // adds `val` to `some_vect_C` and `some_set_C`
    }
}
```

This particular demo code is pretty pointless (it produces identical results in all three sets and all three vectors), but does show how to do the manipulation you need.